# Accessing a variable declared in a Form

Tags: c#, forms

I'm doing a course on learning C# and the task is to create a small converter using windows forms and use a function to perform the conversion.

At the moment I have been able to do everything through defining a variable in the form and having each different button assign a value to the variable, This works fine at the moment since the conversion is happening within an event when the convert button is pushed. But to complete the task I need the conversion to place outside of the form.

The issue I have is I can't figure out how to access the variable I declared within the form and I don't know how I would return the value into the form once I have created the function.

I'm guessing the function would look something like

```
public double conversion(string ConvertIn, string ConvertOut, double Value)
{
    Value = Double.Parse(ValueEntry.Text);
    double Output = (Value / Double.Parse(ConvertIn)) * Double.Parse((ConvertOut));
    FinalOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(Output);

    { 
        return Output;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To Convert I need to Take a variable the User enters into a text box then / by a value selected via a button then multiply by another value selected via a button

But as I said I can't figure out how to get the 3 variables that have been declared in the form, or how I would return the value into the form output textbox.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the most simple way - make the variable **static**.. that will make it "visible" to other parts of your code such as forms

Comment: @ymz  so they are declared as    static string ConvertIn; string ConvertOut;
  static double  Value, Output;           They still don't show up anywhere else

Comment: now open up a new form (let's say Form2) and call them.. assuming your main form is called Form1: Form1.ConvertIn, Form1.ConvertOut

Comment: _"to complete the task I need the conversion to place outside of the form...I don't know how I would return the value into the form"_ -- without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the question is very unclear. Are you saying that you need to define your `conversion()` method outside the form, but that otherwise everything else is still in the form? Please be more specific, showing how you expect to call this method and what you want to do with its returned value. Show enough context to ensure it's possible to understand what you're asking.

Comment: @PeterDuniho  So I just wan't to create a method that converts the numbers input by into form in the program.cs part and then return the converted value back to the form. Everything such as the selection of the amount and units converted is determined by the form

Comment: @ymz Do i need to open a new form? Can't I call them into the main program.cs when I try with the example of what i thought the function would look like it tells me 'conversion': cannot declare instance members in a static class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you've been assigned a homework assignment, in which you have a specific requirement that this method reside in a class other than your `Form` subclass.

The most straightforward way to do this would be to have some simple "utility" class where you can put a static method to do this conversion. The method parameter list should allow your `Form` subclass code to pass the values of interest, and of course the caller will take the return value from the method and assign it to an appropriate member (e.g. `FinalOutput.Text`).

For example:

```
static class Util
{
    public static string conversion(string ConvertIn, string ConvertOut, string Value)
    {
        double c1 = double.Parse(ConvertIn),
            c2 = double.Parse(ConvertOut),
            v = double.Parse(Value);

        return ((v / c1) * c2).ToString();
    }
}
```

You might call it like this:

```
FinalOutput.Text = Util.conversion(ConvertIn.Text, ConvertOut.Text, ValueEntry.Text);
```

Notes:

- Lacking [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I don't really know how the UI is set up. I can infer the `ValueEntry` and `FinalOutput` controls from the little bit of code you did provide, but there's nothing to suggest where the `ConvertIn` and `ConvertOut` values should come from, so I've just assumed controls of those same names. I presume given the above example, you'll be able to pass the actual correct values to the method.
- If this is in fact a homework assignment, as it appears, you will probably still want to consult with your teacher so that you understand better what the above is doing. StackOverflow is not bad for providing actual code solutions to questions, but it's a lot harder to ensure that a student has actually received the explanatory details that are critical to actually *learn* the concept of interest. (Besides, without knowing the exact homework assignment details, while the above is certainly *working* code, it's not necessarily what your teacher actually wanted).

Comment: I got the convert Values via button clicks assigning to a variable in the form .   When I run your example it tells me "'string' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found..."  Is it possible to create a method in the form itself instead of making a class

Comment: _"Is it possible instead that I can create a method inside of the form and not have to create a class?"_ -- yes, of course it is _technically_ possible. But you wrote in your question _"to complete the task I need the conversion to place outside of the form"_, and the above answer is based on that requirement.

Comment: As far as the compiler error goes, as I said you will have to figure out how to pass the correct values yourself, since you didn't provide any context in your question. That said, given the error you are getting it sounds like you could probably just drop the `.Text` in the method call. E.g. write `Util.conversion(ConvertIn, ConvertOut, ValueEntry.Text);` instead.

Comment: Okay dropping the .text fixed that and now it is running correctly Thank you for your help, I think my misunderstanding of what classes were for made me think I needed to create a separate class but both ways work. Thank you for your help through my somewhat muddled explanation